# sql error when insert new product (magento 1.9.0.1)

Tags: magento-1.9, php

i have that error when try to insert new product programatically

> string 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot
>   add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`magento`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_AT

My code is

```
               Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
            $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
                //if(!$product->getIdBySku($single_product['id'])){

            try{
            $product

                ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
                ->setAttributeSetId(9) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
                ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
                ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
                ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time

                ->setSku('214dd21d') //SKU
                ->setName('test name') //product name

                ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
                ->setTaxClassId(1) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
                ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
                ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
                ->setColor('red')
                ->setNewsFromDate(11/10/2014) //product set as new from
                ->setCountryOfManufacture('US') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)

                ->setPrice(2000) //price in form 11.22
                ->setCost(2000) //price in form 11.22
                // ->setSpecialPrice($single_product['price']) //special price in form 11.22
                // ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
                // ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
                // ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
                ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
                //->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price

                ->setMetaTitle('test title')
                ->setMetaKeyword('test keyword')
                ->setMetaDescription('test meta ')

                ->setDescription('test')
                ->setShortDescription('test')

                //->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) //media gallery initialization
                //->addImageToMediaGallery('media/catalog/product/1/0/10243-1.png', array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false) //assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery

                ->setStockData(array(
                                   'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                                   'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
                                   'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                                   'max_sale_qty'=>1, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                                   'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                                   'qty' => 1 //qty
                               )
                )

                ->setCategoryIds(array(3)); //assign product to categories
            $product->save();
            die('done');
          }catch(Exception $e){

            die(var_dump($e->getMessage()));
            //Mage::log($e->getMessage());

           }
       //}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the attribute set ID is 9 and that this attribute set was created correctly?

The error seems to indicate otherwise. This foreign key is responsible for ensuring the integrity between the `catalog_product_entity` table and the `eav_attribute_set` table. In a new installation the ID for the `Default` product attribute set is 4.

Please re-check the attribute sets in the table `eav_attribute_set` called `Default` . There are multiple attribute sets with this name. They are related to different entity types (categories, products, ...). Check the column `entity_type_id`. The ID in this column refers to another table `eav_entity_type` which defines the entity types category, product, ...

An example from a vanilla CE 1.9 install:

- In table `eav_entity_type`, there is an entry with the `entity_type_code` catalog_product. This row has the ID 4.
- Checking `eav_attribute_set`, you'll find an entry with the `entity_type_id` 4 and the `attribute_set_name` Default. In my test installation this row has the ID 4.
- So you'd have to take this ID and use it for the product definition: `$product->setAttributeSetId(4)`;